# What's the correct syntax for passing this class to a reference?

Tags: c++

Say I have two classes:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    int x;
};

class Bar
{
public:
    Foo *foo;
};
```

An instance as follows:

```
Bar *bar;
bar = new Bar();
```

And a function that takes a Foo object by reference:

```
void func(Foo &foo);
```

What is the correct way to call this function with the foo in bar as in bar->foo ?

Comment: `bar->*foo` doesn't work?

Comment: @Sailesh, that syntax is for dereferencing a pointer-to-member, not a member that's a pointer.

Comment: @TobySpeight yes.. realized the mistake as soon as I saw the answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
func(*(bar->foo));
```

Comment: (Parentheses optional, for clarity only)

Answer (score 0):

`bar->foo` is a *pointer* to a foo.  We just need to dereference that pointer:

```
Foo& f = *bar->foo;
func(f);
```

Or (all in one)

```
func(*bar->foo);
```